Can't fetch the multiple option for second level dropdown. It only works for one dropdown option
There is a problem with parse_button item, my script can't fetch the dropdown if the values has multiple options.
Here is the following scenario with multiple combination
Scenario 1 Working
Size
6ft 3in
Capacity
3-6kg
Pack Pieces
1 Piece
Scenario 2 Working
Size
6ft 10in
Capacity
1.54kg - selected
Pack Pieces
1 Piece or 2 Pieces
Scenario 3 Not Working
Size
6ft 4in
Capacity
blank
Pack Pieces
blank
Is it possible for Python to click the button "button_url" first, then extract the second option if it has multiple options then the third level options as well..
import scrapy

class BcfSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'product_spider'
    start_urls = ['https://www.bcf.com.au/p/daiwa-23-td-black-spinning-rod/M675158.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        for button_url in response.css('.swatchanchor::attr(href)').getall():
            yield response.follow(button_url, callback=self.parse_button)
        
    def parse_button(self, response):
        dropdown_options = response.css('.variation-select option')
        dropdown_data = {}
        for option in dropdown_options:
            value = option.css('::attr(value)').get()
            text = option.css('::text').get()
            dropdown_data[text] = value
        yield {'dropdown_data': dropdown_data}



I removed the [selenium-webdriver] tag because you aren't using it. I don't see any reference to beautifulsoup either... are you actually using it? If not, please remove that tag as well.

JeffC I tried the Selenium library, it's not working as expected.

What do you mean by "fetch"? What are you trying to achieve? Do you need to click the option or just get the text? What error are you encountering specifically?

@Payrfix I need to click the buttons in order to extract the values from the dropdown, it depends with the size buttons once it's clicked. The dropdown values rely on size buttons is what I'm referring to.

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

If you want to get all capacities for desired size you have to make an additional request, e.g.:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

id_ = "M675158"
url = f"https://www.bcf.com.au/p/daiwa-23-td-black-spinning-rod/{id_}.html"
api_url = "https://www.bcf.com.au/on/demandware.store/Sites-bcf-au-Site/en_AU/Product-Variation"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

for a in soup.select("li > a.swatchanchor"):
    size = a.text.strip()
    params = {
        "pid": id_,
        f"dwvar_{id_}_size": size,
        "source": "detail",
        "variant_order": "size",
        "Quantity": "1",
        "productlistid": "undefined",
        "format": "ajax",
    }

    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(api_url, params=params).content, "html.parser")

    for c in soup2.select(".capacity option")[1:]:
        print(f"{size:<10} {c.text.strip()}")

Prints:
6ft        10-15kg
6ft 3in    3-6kg
6ft 4in    1-3kg
6ft 4in    1.5-4kg
6ft 4in    5-8kg
6ft 4in    6-12kg
6ft 10in   1.5-4kg
7ft        1-3kg
7ft        1.5-4kg
7ft        2-6kg
7ft        5-10kg
7ft        8-15kg
7ft 2in    1.5-3kg
7ft 4in    2-5kg
7ft 4in    5-8kg
7ft 4in    5-10kg
7ft 4in    10-15kg
7ft 6in    5-10kg
7ft 8in    1.5-4kg
7ft 8in    2-5kg
7ft 9in    15-24kg


How about the third level dropdown? how can I extract the data? I'm having some troubles with this code below
for a in sizesparam_soup.select(".attribute:nth-child(2) option")[1:]: opt2_value = a.text.strip() opt2_label = sizesparam_soup.select_one(".attribute:nth-child(2) .label:last-of-type").text.strip().lower() for b in sizesparam_soup.select(".attribute:nth-child(3) option")[1:]:opt3_value = b.text.strip().replace(" ", "%20")opt3_label = sizesparam_soup.select_one(".attribute:nth-child(3) .label:last-of-type").text.strip().lower().replace(" ", "") print(b)
